# how to login mongo as a specific user

Tags: mongodb

I add a user in mongo, using the

```
use production
db.addUser({user:"user",pwd:"pwd",roles:["read"]})
```

and also authenticate it, using the

```
db.auth("user","pwd")
```

My question is how to login the production database with the user I just created info.

Comment: you just did. that's what db.auth(user, password) did - it authenticated/aka logged into the db you were connected to as that user.

Comment: but when I run command db.listings.drop(), listings is one collection of my database, it still works. Is that right? I create a user has only read permission, but it can drop all the data in database.

Comment: Is your mongod running with the --auth option?

Comment: yes, after I run db.auth("user","pwd"), I still can drop the data in database

Comment: Are you connecting from the host the database is running on? By default, connections from localhost will have full admin access. You can disable this behavior with a startup parameter: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/

Comment: Have you added a user in the `admin` database? If not, there is the [localhost exception](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/#authenticate-with-full-administrative-access-via-localhost) as noted by Mzzi. To test your new "user" account you should also quit the `mongo` shell and login with those credentials. If you are still logged in as an admin user, the privileges are not dropped when you authenticate as a second user.